# C++ left shift operator used inside an array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, partitioning, bit-shift

I found this array declaration in open source software. It reads data from CSV files, compares the tuples, and outputs the best tuples.

```cpp
static const uint32_t SHIFTS[] = { 1 << 0, 1 << 1, 1 << 2, 1 << 3, 1 << 4,
1 << 5, 1 << 6, 1 << 7, 1 << 8, 1 << 9, 1 << 10, 1 << 11, 1 << 12, 1 << 13,
1 << 14, 1 << 15, 1 << 16, 1 << 17, 1 << 18, 1 << 19, 1 << 20, 1 << 21,
1 << 22, 1 << 23, 1 << 24, 1 << 25, 1 << 26, 1 << 27, 1 << 28, 1 << 29, 1 << 30 };
```

I guess this `SHIFTS[]` array is used in **data partitioning**.

Why was the left shift operator used inside the array declaration?

[left shift operator <<](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/left-shift-right-shift-operators-c-cpp/):

> left shifting an integer “x” with an integer “y” denoted as ‘(x<<y)’ is equivalent to multiplying x with 2^y (2 raised to power y).
>
> right shifting an integer “x” with an integer “y” denoted as ‘(x>>y)‘ is equivalent to dividing x with 2^y.

Since the final value of the array would be like the following, why just not declare it as this?

```cpp
static const uint32_t SHIFTS[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384,
32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216,
33554432, 67108864, 134217728, 268435456, 536870912, 1073741824};
```

I tried to compute each shift operation on each element and found the final array value, but I could not figure out why someone would want to declare an array with the left shift operator.

Comment: Because the values are likely not important and less readable (and more error-prone). What is important is to make clear it is the specific shifts.

Comment: or why not just write the number you want in hex (with a comment) - both bits of code that you have posted are unreadable to me

Comment: Neither version is any good; you don't need an array for such regular data as you can easily compute it on the fly: `SHIFTS[i]` is same as `(1 << i)`. It will also be faster since no memory access is involved and shifting registers is extremely fast.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Speaking from my (opinionated) point of view if this code landed in my inbox as part of a code review, I'd rather see the shifts than hex values, unless the author took great care to align the hex so the exact bit positions are clearly visible, *and* I were assured the autoformatting tool wouldn't break that alignment. I'd much rather read `1 << 27` than count the zeros in `0x8000000`. Of course, as rustyx points out, this is better done at runtime, but from a simple readability standpoint, IMO the shifts win out over the hex.

Comment: It just fills a constant array with powers of two. Doing it by a constexpr initializer will avoid typos all together. Demo : https://onlinegdb.com/Hv-eeS07u

Comment: @nanofarad hex numbers with a comment such as "powers of two because ..." would be much clearer to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will almost certainly generate the same static data for the two definitions. The difference is readability to human users.

The declaration using the shifts actually presents a human-readable intent, that the array ought to be full of consecutive powers of two.

In fact, it's sufficiently readable that many readers can verify that the shifts are correct and follow the intended pattern, with only a quick skim.
This makes the code less error-prone, easier to extend in the future (suppose you had to handle shifts up to 2^63 in a later version?), and otherwise easier to read.

On the other hand, readers are not expected to remember that 1073741824 == 2^30, or many other powers of two for that matter. If I had to work with the second sample of code, I'd have to spend quite a bit of effort keeping track of all of the values, calculating them with a calculator, etc.

Comment: I dunno, I feel that's an unreadable mess.   Just use 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, etc.